# Binomial Expansion with fractional or negative indices

Tags: binomial-theorem

### Question:

Expand the function $\frac{2}{(2x - 3)(2x+1)}$ in a series of powers of $x$ up to $x^2$. State the set of values of $x$ for which this expansion is valid.

---

I've come across this question and would like to ask how most of you would tackle it. I've never seen one of this form before as it's my first time tackling fractional or negative indices. Thus I kindly ask to correct me wherever I'm wrong in my attempt:

### My Attempt:

I rewrote $\frac{2}{(2x - 3)(2x+1)}$ as $2(2x - 3)^{-1}(2x+1)^{-1}$ since it seemed to somehow make some more sense. I then followed the simple formula $$1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)x^2}{2!} + \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)x^3}{3!}$$

And substituted it with one of my terms whilst leaving 2 outside: $$2[(2x-3)^{-1}] \equiv 2[1+(-1)(2x)+\frac{(-1)(-2)(2x)^2}{2(1)}]$$

As the question requests up to $x^2$. Once working all of that out I got:
$$2[1-2x-4x^2]$$
$\therefore$ The expansion is valid when $x$ is between $-\frac{1}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$

And wrote it down as an inequality: $$-\frac{1}{4} < x < \frac{1}{4}$$

### Second Attempt

I went ahead and worked it out using Partial Fractions. Seems to make much more sense.

$$\frac{2}{(2x - 3)(2x+1)} \equiv \frac{A}{(2x-3)}+\frac{B}{(2x+1)}$$

Rewrite as..
$$2 = A(2x+1)+B(2x-3)$$
$$2 = \frac{2}{(2x+1)}-\frac{2}{(2x-3)}$$

And once again rewrite as..
$$2(2x+1)^{-1} - 2(2x-3)^{-1}$$
$$2^{-1}(2x+1)^{-1}+6^{-1}(\frac{2}{3}x-1)^{-1}$$

From here I worked each expansion separately however got stuck at a certain point.

$$\frac{1}{2}[1+(-1)(2x)+\frac{(-1)(-2)(2x)^2}{2!} ] = \frac{1}{2}[1 - 2x - 4x^2 ]$$

And..

$$\frac{1}{6}[1 + (-1)(\frac{2}{3}x) + \frac{(-1)(-2)(\frac{2}{3}x)^2}{2!} ] = \frac{1}{2}[1 - \frac{2}{3}x - (\frac{2}{3}x)^2]$$

I'm not sure if I'm doing it right from here onwards

$$\frac{1}{2}[1-2x-4x^2] - \frac{1}{6}[1-\frac{2}{3}x-(\frac{2}{3}x^2)]$$

And my final answer..
$$\frac{1}{2} - x - 2x^2 - \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{9}x - \frac{2}{27}x^2 = \frac{2}{3} - \frac{8}{9}x - \frac{56x^2}{27}$$

---

I'm sorry if this is completely wrong, it's literally my first time trying it out however it makes sense to consult an experienced person before entering the topic thinking I understand it when I don't.

Comment: how a bout starting with Partial Fractions first. this kind of question is crying for partial fractions I think :)

Comment: @Daniel - Very true, I did quite think that aswell. Might rework it using partials instead.

Comment: do you simply need to find the power series representation for this function? I am not sure a bout the question. But if so, it will be useful to start with partial fractions and use the series representation of the function 1/(1-x)

Comment: @Daniel - I have written the entire question, so from what it seems he is simply asking for the expansion of the function up to $x^2$ and state all the possible values of $x$ for that particular expansion to be valid. I shall give it a second attempt.

Comment: Your "simple formula" is a simple formula for ... what, exactly? I think you will find that what it is a simple formula for does not match $(2x-3)^{-1}$. But you can write $(2x-3)^{-1}=-(1/3)/(1-(2x/3))$ and then use the formula for the sum of a geometric series.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - I am currently appending my second attempt to the main question, it tackles it by first using partial fractions and then use the formula I showed. Hopefully it's correct.

Comment: if you are only interested in finding terms up to the quadratic it is much easier to write $\frac{2}{(2x-3)(2x+1)} = a + bx + cx^2 + \cdots.$  multiply both sides by $-3 -4x + 4x^2$ and equate the coefficients of $1, x$ and $x^2.$

Comment: I have posted my second attempt, answer seems to be very close to that of rubik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Binomial Theorem for negative powers says that for $|x| < 1$
$$(1+x)^{-1} = 1 - x + x^2 + \mathcal{o}(x^2)$$

Therefore we have:
$$\frac 2{(2x-3)(2x+1)} = \frac 1{2(2x-3)} - \frac 1{2(2x+1)} = -\frac 16\left(1-\frac 23x\right)^{-1} - \frac 12\left(1+2x \right )^{-1} = -\frac16\left(1 + \frac 23x + \frac 49x^2\right)-\frac 12\left(1 - 2x + 4x^2 \right ) = \boxed{-\frac 23 + \frac 89 x - \frac{56}{27}x^2}$$

This holds for $|x| < \frac12$.

Comment: My oh my, I actually did it right!

Comment: @Juxhin: If you look at the plot they're somewhat close, but the approximation is bad even at $1/3$. If you go up to $x^5$ it gets better, but it converges slowly. https://www.desmos.com/screenshot/i5c0rqshe8 (in blue is the approximant)

Comment: Now I'm getting a solid grasp of what you have done, my error seems to be due to how I arranged everything. Also that website seems very cool. Thanks for the share.

Comment: Can you please explain why is $x \in [-1/2,1/2]$?

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html That is why. There is a theorem about it.

Comment: @Shocky2 It's very simple and I've already mentioned the reason (Binomial Theorem for negative powers) at the top of the answer. The first equation holds for $|x| < 1$. In the second equation we want to expand ${(1 + 2x)}^{-1}$. Since we substituted $x$ for $2x$, the new condition is $|2x| < 1$, which is equivalent to $|x| < 1/2$.

Comment: @rubik Thank you and sorry, I woke up stupid today. Literally, slow thinking. Hope to get some sleep and do better tomorrow.