# Series and quadratic approximation

Tags: approximation, binomial-theorem

Been working out series for the past day and have come across this question. I would kindly ask how I ought to tackle it, I've done Binomial and Maclauren's however this seems to require another method.

---

Given that x is so small that $x^3$ and higher powers of $x$ may be neglected, write down a quadratic approximation of each of the following:
$$1. \frac{1+3x}{2+x}  2. \frac{2+5x}{(1-3x)^2}$$

Those happen to be the two questions to work out. I kindly ask to not give me the answer immediately but **simply** steer me to the right direction.

### My Attempt(s)

---

Started off by rewriting everything$$\frac{1+3x}{2+x} = \frac{1}{2+x} +  \frac{1}{2+x}3x$$

Then proceeded to factor 2 out to bring the it to the form $(1+y)$ $$\frac{1}{2(1+\frac{x}{2})} +  \frac{1}{2(1+\frac{x}{2})}3x$$

For convenience sake *(personal thing I guess)* I rewrote it as:$$2^{-1}(1+\frac{x}{2})^{-1} + 2^{-1}(1+\frac{x}{2})^{-1}3x$$

And therefore expanded everything like so:$$\frac{1}{2}\left [ 1+(-1)(\frac{x}{2}) + \frac{(-1)(-2)(\frac{x}{2})^2}{2!}  + ...\right ] + \frac{3x}{2}\left [1+(-1)(\frac{x}{2}) + \frac{(-1)(-2)(\frac{x}{2})^2}{2!}  + ...\right ]$$

Simplified everything down to:$$\frac{1}{2}\left [ 1- \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4} + ...\right ] + \frac{3x}{2}\left [  1- \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{4} + ...\right ]$$

Disregarded any terms that where degree 3 or higher *(there was only one)*:
$$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x}{4} - \frac{x^2}{8} + \frac{3x}{2} - \frac{3x^2}{4}$$

And thus finally arrived with:
$$\frac{1}{2} - \frac{5x}{4} - \frac{5x^2}{8}$$

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, note that $\frac{1+3x}{2+x} = \frac{1}{2+x} + 3x * \frac{1}{2+x}$. Now, try to put $\frac{1}{2+x}$ into the form $\frac{1}{1-y}$, and use the fact that, for $|y|<1$, we have $\frac{1}{1-y} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y^n$.

The second question can be answered similarly. You just have to determine the series for $\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}$ using the series $\frac{1}{1-y} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} y^n$.

Let me know if you need more help.

**Full Answer:** We have
$$\frac{1+3x}{2+x} = \frac{1+3x}{2} \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{x}{2})}.$$
The term on the right is equal to
$$\frac{1}{1-(-\frac{x}{2})} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left(-\frac{x}{2} \right)^n = 1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{4} - \dots$$
Therefore,
$$\frac{1+3x}{2} \frac{1}{1-(-\frac{x}{2})} = \frac{1+3x}{2} \left( 1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^2}{4} - \dots \right) \approx \frac{(1+3x)(4-2x+x^2)}{8} = \frac{4-2x+x^2+12x-6x^2+3x^3}{8} \approx \frac{-5x^2+10x+4}{8}.$$

This is equivalent to your answer except for the sign on $-\frac{5x}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When he asks for a quadratic approximation, what is it he's asking for exactly *(as in, what does it look like)*? Do I have to expand like I did at the end of [my previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057072/binomial-expansion-with-fractional-or-negative-indices)?

Comment: In regards to rewriting it, did you simply rewrite $\frac{1}{2+x}$ as $\frac{1}{2(1+\frac{x}{2})}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The final answer should be a quadratic polynomial. You get this polynomial from the infinite series by ignoring all powers of $x$ bigger than $x^2$.

Comment: And yes, just factor a 2 out of the denominator to get it to the form you want for the first problem.

Comment: Alright. Thanks again for your patience, I'll try working it out and then amending my attempt in the original question. If you so happened to work it out already, could you possibly edit the answer with your answer?

Comment: I've went ahead and posted my full attempt step by step. Hope this helps.

Comment: Alright great. Got the answer right then. Thank's again @Mark